# Access denied when assuming role as IAM user via boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

**Issue**

I have an IAM user, and an IAM role. I am trying to configure the IAM user to have permission to assume the IAM role using STS. I am not sure why I receive an "Access Denied" error.

**Details**

IAM role: `arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/athena_access`

IAM user: `arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/athena-external-user`

IAM user policy to allow assume role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "StsAssumeRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/athena_access"
        }
    ]
}
```

Code:

```
import boto3
os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = '...'
os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = '...'

client = boto3.client('sts')
role_to_assume_arn='arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/athena_access'
role_session_name='test_session'
response=client.assume_role(
    RoleArn=role_to_assume_arn,
    RoleSessionName=role_session_name
)
```

Error:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/athena-external-user is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/athena_access

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, I found the solution shortly after posting the question.

The IAM role needs to have a TrustRelationship policy for the user that will assume the role.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/athena-external-user"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I just answered one very similar to this recently. The trust relationship piece is important. It also gets a little more involved if multiple accounts are in play.