# Why is `botocore-session-id#` being attached to my Amazon Resource Number (arn:) when trying to `assume-role` via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, botocore

Up until now I have been able to run `aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::<accountID>:role/<iam_role> --role-session-name <a_session_name> --profile <the_profile_name>` without a hitch...

Now I'm getting an error `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::<accountID>:assumed-role/<iam_role>/botocore-session-xxxxx is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::<accountId>:role/<iam_role>`

Is this due to me being in an assumed role state and then attempting to assume the same role again? If that is the case then whats the solution for clearing out the botocore cache?

- *I have cleared the ~/.aws/cache directory*
- *I have been successful assuming this role until today, no security credentials have been removed from my AWS account*
- *I've killed and restated iTerm session*
- *executing `aws sts get-caller-identity --profile picklerick` nets me the same results: both `arn:` and `userId` have the same `botocore-session-xxxxx` attached*

these question are not dupes of this question:

1. [Access denied when assuming role as IAM user via boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58616071/access-denied-when-assuming-role-as-iam-user-via-boto3)
2. [AWS cli: not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60334096/aws-cli-not-authorized-to-perform-stsassumerole-on-resource)
3. [python boto3 error: Not authorized to perform assumed role on resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64600733/python-boto3-error-not-authorized-to-perform-assumed-role-on-resource?rq=1)

if any of this makes sense to you then you might also be able to explain what caused this in the first place - i've had no issues up until this, never cared or saw mention of boto

Comment: the end goal is to deploy to an AWS S3 Bucket via `aws s3 sync dist s3://thebucket--acl public-read --profile picklerick` which I was just successful running - so my guess is that something within AWS is running a script that attaches the botocore session id and that id is required for API requests

Comment: You probably have some environment variables already set with credentials

Comment: nope - i've unset everything returned from `env | grep AWS`

Comment: Hmm, then it's probably somewhere else in the credential loading precidence: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html#cli-configure-quickstart-precedence are you running in a container, or on an EC2 instance?

Comment: Does `aws sts get-caller-identity` work? What does it give you?

Comment: EC2 instance - i'm using named profiles, each profile contains the access key id, secrect key, role arn, and region as well as the source_profile that points to that user with the access key and secret key defined in the credentials

Comment: Do you have an instance profile/role attached to the instance - it's possibly falling through to instance metadata

Comment: running get caller identity returns the creds but they all have the `botocore-session-xxx` attached - and since Im able to run the sync, I guess it doesn't matter but I still would like to understand whats happening behind the scene

Comment: But is the caller identity the user/role you expect?

Comment: yes - its the right one 

dear AWS, thank you for your documentation, now please trim out all the fluff, dead links, and deprecated content

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that IAM roles no longer implicitly trust themselves, so you need to adjust the trust policies to add the role itself to the list. For anyone having the same problem like me, you may read the following blog post.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/announcing-an-update-to-iam-role-trust-policy-behavior/